# How to get the IP address from /etc/hosts?

Tags: python, ubuntu-server

I have the following line in my `/etc/hosts` file

```
54.230.202.149 gs2.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net
```

What I'm trying to do is, find the line `gs2` in the `/etc/hosts` file and get the current IP address.  This is what I have, but it doesn't find the DNS or return the IP address. It tells me that my current IP address is 'None'.

```
try:
     with open('/etc/hosts', 'r') as f:
         for line in f:
             host_ip = re.findall(r"\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b.+(?=gs2)", line)
             if host_ip:
                 current_ip = host_ip[0].strip()
             else:
                 current_ip = 'None'
except:
    current_ip = 'Unknown'

c.execute('INTERT INTO status VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)',
           ('Current Configured IP', current_ip))
```

Not sure what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do this using .split(), which will split your line based on whitespace into separate indexed elements.

Also note that using this approach removes the need for `host_ip[0].strip()`, because all whitespace between IP address and hostname is removed during the `split()` operation. You can just use `host_ip[0]`.

```
try:
     with open('/etc/hosts', 'r') as f:
         for line in f:
             host_ip = line.split()
             if host_ip and 'gs2' in host_ip[1][0:3]:
                 current_ip = host_ip[0]
             else:
                 current_ip = 'None'
except:
    current_ip = 'Unknown'
```

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split:

(See URL for further discussion of split()).

> str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
>
> ...
>
> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a None separator returns [].
>
> ...

Comment: Updated my Answer to account for 'gs2' and give proper index for that string.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex was working, I think the way the script was reading the lines was skewed a little bit as when I tested it didn't read my lines after a blank space. I ended up adding the lines variable. I am sure there is a more pythonic way to achieve this but it works.

```
import re

try:
    with open(r'/etc/hosts') as f:
        lines = [line for line in f.read().splitlines() if line]
        for line in lines:
            host_ip = re.findall(r"\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b.+(?=gs2)", line)
            print(host_ip)
            if host_ip:
                current_ip = host_ip[0].strip()
                print(current_ip)
except:
    current_ip = 'Unknown'
```